# How to use ajax in alert modal magento 2?

Tags: magento2, ajax, modal, magento2.2.8

I have this ajax code and i want to use alert modal of magento 2.

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#vendor_search").on('click',function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                var input = $("#customer_id").val();
                var param = { data : input};
                var url = '<?php  echo $block->getUrl('kyanh/vendor/getinfo');?>';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: param,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    showLoader: true
                }).done(function(data)
                {
                    var ar = [
                        data['cus_id'],
                        data['lname'],
                        data['email']
                    ];
                    alert(ar);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pls help me, tks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
<script>
    require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
    ],function($,alert){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#vendor_search").on('click',function(event){

                event.preventDefault();
                var input = $("#customer_id").val();
                var param = { data : input};
                var url = '<?php  echo $block->getUrl('kyanh/vendor/getinfo');?>';
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    showLoader: true,
                    dataType:'json',
                    data: param,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(result){                   
                     alert({
                            title: 'Some title',
                            content: result.msg,
                            actions: {
                                always: function(){}
                            }
                        });

                    }
                 });


            });
        });
    });   

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: tks very much bro ^^ this code is working

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: Good answer. +1